# Is there a typescript interface for html CustomElement?

Tags: html, typescript, custom-element

I am trying to implement a web custom element in typescript.
I have found that the custom element gets its life cycle callbacks like

- `connectedCallback()`
- `adoptedCallback()`
- `attributeChangedCallback()`

Is there a typescript interface for these callbacks?
I can write these methods with appropriate signature but I would prefer to use an existing definition.

Comment: This question is already a few years old: 1) No, no there are no definitions for those Web API/Custom Component lifecycle callbacks built directly into TypeScript.  2) Yes, they can be easily implemented in TypeScript.  A good starting point would be adopting the JS examples referenced on the MDN page:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements > https://github.com/mdn/web-components-examples/blob/main/expanding-list-web-component/main.js 3) Another useful resource might be "lit": https://lit.dev/docs/

Answer (score -1):

Yes,  Typescript has an interface called `HTMLElementTagNameMap` which provides a way to define and use custom elements with type definition.

Example:-

`interface MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement { .... }`

`// Register the custom element<br> customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement);`

Comment: `HTMLElementTagNameMap` defines the list of tags, not the interface for custom elements